# Removing Ansii chars while writing to file

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have converted some bytes of data & written them to a text file. In the text file I can see few ANSI chars `[[2K[90m]` been written which does not display if I do print how can I avoid these chars to be displayed in the textfile

sample output from textfile

```
[2K[90m[00024237ms][DBG ]: ::send_request, request_id:  (19), token_id: 5[0m


[2K[90m[00024250ms][DBG ][CELL]: , request_id:  (19), token_id: 5 error: 0[0m
```

for decoding the bytes I have done

```
newdata = Bytesdata.decode("utf-8")
```

& for writing to text

```
with open("test.txt", "a+") as file:
    file.write(newdata)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make use of regular expressions to eliminate ansi characters:

```
import re
def escape_ansi(line):
    ansi_escape =re.compile(r'(\x9B|\x1B\[)[0-?]*[ -\/]*[@-~]')
    return ansi_escape.sub('', line)
print(escape_ansi(line = '\t\u001b[0;35mSomeText\u001b[0m\u001b[0;36m172.18.0.2\u001b[0m'))
```

[Source](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/How-can-I-remove-the-ANSI-escape-sequences-from-a-string-in-python)